# We are making a for loop that should go through all rows and column in a matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

We are wondering how we can define our rows and columns so we can insert all rows and columns into this function

```
% V is our matrix
% i = columns of the matrix V
%j = rows of the matrix V
function quantity = neighbours(V,i,j)
    quantity = sum(sum(V(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1)))-V(i,j)
end
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: codeV = [1 1 1; 1 1 1;1 1 1]
for i=1:length(V)
    for j 1:length(V)'

function quantity = neighbours(V,i,j)
quantity = sum(sum(V(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1)))-V(i,j)
end`enter code here`
    end
end`

Comment: We do not to how to vary the columns and rows in the function

Comment: could you give an example what kind of data you have and what kind of output you want? I feel like your code would only work with `i=2` and `j=2`. is your problem that it should also work with 1 and 3?

Comment: Our problem is that we have a matrix 16x16 and we want our function input i and j to correspond to i= the matrix rows j= the matrix columns. We want to create that can go through all columns and rows in our function. The functions purpose is to count the amount of neighbours a element is the matrix has

Comment: So you want to create a Matrix, in which each element contains the sum of all neighboring elements right?

Comment: Well yes the function will create that, we just don't know how to input the rows and columns as variables in the function quantity

Answer (score 1):

If you desire the output for the entire matrix V, you can define a window of your desired neighborhood size & pattern and then convolve your matrix V with it:

E.g. for a sum of 8 neighborhood you can do:

```
function quantity = neighbours(V)
    w = [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1]; % define a window for summing 8-neigborhood of a pixel 
    quantity  = conv2(V, w, 'same'); % result matrix
end
```

If you need say 4-neigborhood, you can replace w above by:

```
w = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure that I understand the issue completly, but I feel like we wont get any further without a try. So this your function but it takes the edges into account. If you are new to MatLab this has to be safed in a extra file called 'neighbours.m'.

```
function quantity = neighbours(V,i,j)
height=size(V,1);
width=size(V,2);
quantity = sum(sum(V(max(i-1,1):min(i+1,height),max(1,j-1):min(j+1,width))))-V(i,j);
end
```

If the row or column is at an edge of the matrix, lets say (1,1) the area is reduced to stay inside the matrix. otherwise you would get an error (probably 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.') With that you could just loop through the matrix which is not ver effient but will do the trick. This code can run anywhere except for the 'neighbours.m' file

```
codeV = ones(5,3);
amount_of_neighbors = zeros(size(zcodeV));
for i=1:size(zcodeV,1) %height
    for j=1:size(zcodeV,2) %width
        amount_of_neighbors(i,j) = neighbours(codeV,i,j);
    end
end

disp(amount_of_neighbors)
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for helping us. Secondly we have solved the issue of rows and columns at the edge by adding a frame of zeros around the matrix by using the padarray function

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a strange idea, but it should be very efficient! For this one you just have to make sure, that your matrix `V` has the same amount of rows as columns. The function will output a matrix with the same dimensions as `V` containing in each position the sum of all direct neighbours (diagonal neighbours not included).

```
function quantity = neighbours(V)
    n = length(V(1,:)); % Size of quadratic matrix
    v = ones(n,1);  % Vector used to create matrix A
    A = diag(v,1) + diag(v,-1);
    quantity = V*A+(V'*A)';
end
```

Explanation: Instead of going through the Matrix iteratively, what can cost a lot of computational time for large systems you employ two simple matrix operations.

A looks like this:

```
  [0 1 0 . .]
  [1 0 1 0 .]
A=[0 1 0 1 .]
  [. 0 1 0 .]
  [. . . . .]
```

Important: Just works for quadratic matrices!

Comment: Thank you for helping us! It really means a lot. Just to clarify, the function you have created, does it summarize a elements neighbours?

Comment: Yes, it adds the elements that are over, under and left and right.

Comment: Okey but what does the matrix A do?

Comment: Matrix A provides the selection of the elements, that are supposed to be added up. Make an experiment, copy the function and use it on a small example matrix, lets say on a ones matrix. The Matrix multiplication implicitly tells the function, which factors it should include. It also respects the "missing values" at the boundary of V.